# Read random sample of files on S3 with Pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-s3, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a bucket on S3 that contains 1000 files. Each is about 1GB. I would like to read random sample of this files. Let's say 5% of all files. This is how I do it

`fileDF = sqlContext.jsonRDD(self.sc.textFile(self.path).sample(withReplacement=False, fraction=0.05, seed=42).repartition(160))`

But it seems above code will read all the files and then take samples. While I want to take samples of files and read them. Could somebody help?

Comment: What is self.path? Does it use globbing?

Comment: _self.path_ is a self variable in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your favorite method to list the files under the path, take a sample of the names, and then use RDD union:

```
import pyspark
import random

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName = "Sampler")
file_list = list_files(path)
desired_pct = 5
file_sample = random.sample(file_list, int(len(file_list) * desired_pct / 100))
file_sample_rdd = sc.emptyRDD()
for f in file_sample:
    file_sample_rdd = file_sample_rdd.union(sc.textFile(f))
sample_data_rdd = file_sample_rdd.repartition(160)
```

Here's one possible quick and dirty implementation of "list_files" that will list the files under a "directory" on S3:

```
import os
def list_files(path, profile = None):
    if not path.endswith("/"):
        raise Exception("not handled...")
    command = 'aws s3 ls %s' % path
    if profile is not None:
        command = 'aws --profile %s s3 ls %s' % (profile, path)
    result = os.popen(command)
    _r = result.read().strip().split('\n')
    _r = [path + i.strip().split(' ')[-1] for i in _r]
    return _r
```

Comment: This is great idea. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Does the for-loop run single-threaded? I don't believe so but I may be wrong. I'm looking to achieve the same outcome, but with the use of Spark to read a massive number of "randomly specified" file paths in parallel.